# Rails 5, monkeypatch on Models error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a fresh new application in Ruby on Rails that uses rails 5.1 and ruby 2.3.1

All my Models follow the pattenr

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  ##### AUDITED
  audited

  ##### GEOCODE
  reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :lng

  ##### RELATIONSHIPS
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, optional: true, touch: true
end
```

inheriting from `ApplicationRecord`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  ##### SCOPES
  default_scope { where(deleted: false) }

  ##### SOBRESCREVENDO O MÉTODO DESTROY DO ACTIVERECORD
  def destroy
    run_callbacks(:destroy)
    self.update_attribute(:deleted, true)
  end
end
```

Everything works well on Development ENV, but to work in Production I need to set `config.eager_load = false` to false at `config/environments/production.rb`. If I did not do it, this erros raises:

> TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Address

There are no other `ApplicationRecord` or `Address` classes, what is wrong?

Comment: do you have two `Address` classes in your project?

Comment: what server are you running on production?

Comment: Hello, @emaillenin the only uniq class named Address is my Model;

Comment: @seethrough I'm running on a Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: I was meaning what ruby server